# Passing part of table name to query

Tags: mysql

I have a database that keeps a table logs - each log id will be numeric
There are matching tables to join on that are NAMED log + the numeric logId

I need to be able to join these tables based on a log id that will be passed

ex:
SELECT * from ACTIVITIES a
INNER JOIN (LOG + LogID) l2 ON a.activityID = l2.activityID

The 'logID' will be passed as a paramater
SO if logID is 100 I am looking for table log100

How can I do this?

Comment: passed as a parameter from your query on activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a dynamic sql statement in order for you to execute queries on dynamic tables.

having the log ID as the parameter, create a stored proc accepting one parameter:

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetTableLogs
@logID int

as

DECLARE
@select varchar(2000)

SET @select = 'SELECT * from ACTIVITIES a INNER JOIN LOG' + @logID + ' l2 ON a.activityID = l2.activityID'

EXECUTE (@select)

:)

Answer (score 1):

SQL requires that table names be fixed before you pass the query to `prepare()`. You can't use a parameter for the table name. Not part of the table name, nor the whole table name.

So you must form the table name in a variable in your application code and then use that variable in the SQL query.

Example (pseudocode, like PHP):

```
$logid = 100;
$tablename = "log{$logid}";
$sql = "SELECT * from ACTIVITIES a INNER JOIN `{$tablename}` l2 ON a.activityID = l2.activityID";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

I'd encourage you to check out MySQL's [table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) feature. You may be able to avoid having so many log tables, and just treat them as individual partitions within one whole table.